# Menu will open but not close

Tags: jquery

Ive got this so far

```
        var main = function() {
      /* Push the body and the nav over by 285px over */
      $('.fa-plus').click(function() {

        $(this).removeClass( "fa-plus" ).addClass( "fa-times" );

        $('#side-menu').animate({
          left: "0px"
        }, 200);


        $('#content-area').animate({
          left: "200px"
        }, 140);
      });

      /* Then push them back */
      $('.fa-times').click(function() {

        $(this).removeClass( "fa-times" ).addClass( "fa-plus" );

        $('#side-menu').animate({
          left: "-285px"
        }, 200);

        $('#content-area').animate({
          left: "0px"
        }, 200);
      });
    };


    $(document).ready(main);
```

Full script and html here http://jsfiddle.net/sd6b5my4/

What im trying to achieve is when you press on fa-plus the menu opens and changes the fa-plus to fa-times giving the impression of it transforming, however the script to close it and turn the fa-times back to fa-plus doesn't seem to be working

can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event listener `$('.fa-times').click(function() { ... });` never even gets called because at the time the script is executed, there are no elements with class `.fa-times`. When you change the element's class, the initial event listener is still attached to the element, but the expected event listener isn't.

One solution would be to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and bind the click events to a constant parent element. In this case, `document`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wc99ms2e/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.fa-plus', function () {
    // ...
});

$(document).on('click', '.fa-times', function () {
    // ...
});
```

---

Alternatively, a better option would be to use one `click` event listener, and then add conditional logic to determine what class the element has.

For instance:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/r9vga8um/)

```
$('.toggleableIcon').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('fa-plus')) {
        $(this).removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-times");
        $('#side-menu').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200);
        $('#content-area').animate({
            left: "200px"
        }, 140);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("fa-times").addClass("fa-plus");
        $('#side-menu').animate({
            left: "-285px"
        }, 200);

        $('#content-area').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `$('.fa-times').click()` is not bound to the element yet because the element you're trying to bind this event to doesn't have the `fa-times` class yet. It gets the class only when it's clicked on. One solution is event delegation as mentioned by the other answer.

Other solution could be to create 2 elements - a plus button and a cross button, with the cross button hidden initially.

So, the markup would look something like:

```
<i class="fa fa-times"></i><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
```

And the script would change to:

```
var main = function() {
      // Hide the cross initially.
      $(".fa-times").hide();

      $('.fa-plus').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();        // Hide the plus
        $(".fa-times").show(); // Show the cross
        ...
      });

      $('.fa-times').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();        // Hide the cross
        $(".fa-plus").show();  // Show the plus
        ...
      });
}
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sd6b5my4/2/)

Comment: ..but then the icon isn't animated anymore.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice that. I don't think that the exact animation would be easily possible in this solution.